# CopyManager only delimit once

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to import a password list into a postgresql database. Is there any way to delimit a line only once or only at the first occurrence of the delimiter character?

Data to import:

```
demo@mail.ru:123
demo@mail.de:ab:c
```

My importing code:

```
import org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager;
import org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection;

CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) connection);
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
copyManager.copyIn("COPY db FROM STDIN DELIMITER ':' ", fileReader);
```

This code will fail at the second example as it contains two `:` characters. Any ideas or suggestions to solve this?

Thanks for any help!

Suggestion to escape second `:`:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: extra data after last expected column
  Where: COPY pwned, line 1: "user@demo.pl:123":abc"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1116)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.endCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:965)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyInImpl.endCopy(CopyInImpl.java:45)
    at org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager.copyIn(CopyManager.java:181)
    at org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager.copyIn(CopyManager.java:156)
    at TxtToPostgreSQL.FileToPostgreSQL.fileToPostgre(FileToPostgreSQL.java:22)
    at TxtToPostgreSQL.Import.main(Import.java:31)
```

Comment: Do you use this class? https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html

Comment: Yes it is, I've added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command supports the `ESCAPE` option. Use this together with escaping the colons in your data. Since `ESCAPE` defaults to `QUOTE` which defaults to `"`, change your data to this:

```
demo@mail.ru:123
demo@mail.de:ab":c
```

Also `DELIMITER` must be a single one-byte character. Your SQL should be

```
COPY db FROM STDIN DELIMITER ':'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have roughly 1 TB of documents where I can't just add a escape character to each needed line...